# Create xml tree from xPath expression using xslt

Tags: xslt

I have a sample source xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<shiporder orderid="orderid1">
  <item>
    item1
  </item>
  <item>
    item2
  </item>
</shiporder>
```

The assumptions for the transformation of my source xml is that I have a list of xPaths in this case `/shiporder[1]/item[1]` and `/shiporder[1]/item[2]` and the information that I have to transform the content of those nodes into  `Customer[1]/adress[1]` and `Customer[1]/adress[2]`. In detail the result should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
    <customer>
      <adress>
        item1
      </adress>
      <adress>
        item2
      </adress>
    </customer>
```

Now I'm looking for a template which applies for each path in my source list `["/shiporder[1]/item"]` and transform the inner text of that nodes into nodes with respect to `["Customer[1]/adress"]`.

First of all I thought to create templates like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:func="http://www.functx.com">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/shiporder[1]">
        <Customer>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item"/>
        </Customer>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/shiporder[1]/item">
      <adress>
         <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
      </adress>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But later I was thinking about a function which combines the implicit call of the templates in a recursive way. I hope it is clear from here on other wise I could add some pseudo code what kind of function I have in mind.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please provide an example of the input and the expected output.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, please see my edits.

Comment: If the parameter of the function is supposed to be a string, shouldn't the examples not pass in a string? `func:subTree(Customer[1]/adress[1])` passes in the result of evaluating the XPath expression `Customer[1]/adress[1])`. And if the function is supposed to create nodes, why do you use `<xsl:value-of select="func:subTree(Customer[1]/adress[1])"/>` to handle the result? That would not even output the nodes returned but rather only their string value. And more importantly, given input and output, why do you need a function, why doesn't it suffice to use the templates to create the nodes?

Comment: To further explain the last sentence in my previous comment, why does http://xsltransform.net/6rewNxy not suffice to solve the problem? It uses plain XSLT without any need to try to generate and merge nodes based on XPath expressions?

Comment: @StellaMaris This seems to be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @michael.hor257k I think there are a lot of misunderstandings, please see my edited post.